# how can I change the height of a jquery flexslider belongs to jquery.flexslider-min.js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, flexslider

My wordpress theme contains a jquery flexslider (version:jquery.flexslider-min.js) and the problem is that when I've tried to change the height of it by modifying the height parameter of the slider (by setting fix and auto)  in .css and uploading narrower pictures it appeared that the slider was displayed in the intended shape but the navigation arrows (left, right) got to the bottom of the slider instead of its original place in the middle.

I would be really thankful if someone could help and give an exact solution to the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to say exactly what the problem is, but I have had this issue in the past when positioning items using a static value. Essentially, the height changes but the static position doesn't which leaves your element offset a bit. If *this* is your issue you can fix it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-nav-container">
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li><a class="flex-prev">Previous</a></li>
        <li><a class="flex-next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-nav-container { position: relative; height: 300px; //or whatever }
.flex-direction-nav a { position: absolute; height:30px; top: 50%; margin-top: -15px; }
.flex-prev { left: 0; }
.flex-next { right: 0; }
```

That will center the top of the arrow element to the 50% spot on the slider's height. By adding the negative margin as half of the height of the arrow you are essentially centering the arrow vertically regardless of the height of the slider.

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WzLLV/)

Try changing the height of `.slider` to see what is actually happening. I added some color to show the elements.

Comment: Don't you have an idea that in what way can i go further in the issue? Sincerely, Zoltiano

Comment: The HTML I put in was just for the example. For flexslider, you just need to copy the attributes in the `.arrow` class to the directional control nav for flexslider.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I get it roughly what you're saying but I don't find "arrow" class or attributes neither in my homepage.php nor in style.css file. The jquery flexslider used in the theme is the following: jquery.flexslider-min.js.

Comment: The classes are `.flex-nav-container` instead of `.slider`, `.flex-direction-nav a` instead of `.arrow`, `.flex-prev` instead of `.left-arrow` and `.flex-next` instead of `.right-arrow`. The HTML is generated with flexslider, so you shouldn't have to do anything there. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you.
Is it possible that should I make some modifications in jquery.flexslider-min.js file?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it in the JS file, you can put it in your own stylesheet and it should override the styles that flexslider uses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Yes, of course I will click on it but I will delete from my comments if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
.flexslider .slides img {
   max-width: 100%; 
   height: 748px; //set height in pixel here
   display: block;
 }
```

Comment: can you share the fiddle'

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but meanwhile the problem is solved so no need for further help in this issue. Thank you.